# Excluding relatableQuery in edit form view of Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have 2 resources: Product and Inventory (BelongsToMany relationship)

The pivot table (`inventory_product`) has an extra field is `quantity` (Storing quantity of the product in an inventory).

When using BelongToMany field, it works correctly but the dropdown list still shows all the possible options even the ones already attached. Therefore, I use relatableQuery method to exclude attached ones from the query.

```
public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        // Get the current resource.
        $resourceId = $request->route()->parameter('resourceId');

        // Get the array of product ids that already attached.
        $attachedItems = app(self::$model)->whereHas('inventories', function ($query) use ($resourceId) {
            $query->where('inventory_id', $resourceId);
        })->get()->pluck('id');

        return $query->whereNotIn('id', $attachedItems);
    }
```

But the problem is when I go to the edit form to adjust the `quantity` field it doesn't allow me to do that because of the validation. The dropdown menu is empty because above code filtered them. So how can I avoid the above code in edit form view?

I already tried to get the `parameter` from the `NovaRequest`, but it didn't work :(

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two dropdowns, one for Product, which should be filled with current product ID and one for Inventory, that list all products?
If so, then you should return the full $query in the products dropdown and an altered $query for the inventory dropdown.

Something like this:

```
$fieldResourceType = $request->route()->parameter('field');
return $fieldResourceType == 'inventory' ? $query->whereNotIn('id', $attachedItems) : $query;
```